# How to updated numRows on Amazon Spectrum based on a count from a query

Tags: amazon-redshift, airflow, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Hi I'm trying to automate a workflow in Airflow where I am going to be appending rows to an external Spectrum table daily and I need to alter the numRows on the spectrum table by extracting the count of the existing table + the new count of rows I am appending.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.my_external_table
    (
    id INTEGER,
    barkdata_timestamp timestamp,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp
    )
    PARTITIONED BY (asofdate timestamp)
    STORED AS PARQUET
    LOCATION 's3://<SOME BUCKET>/manifest'
   table properties ('numRows'= '<some number>';

ALTER TABLE spectrum.my_external_table
    ADD PARTITION (asofdate='2021-03-03 00:00:00') LOCATION 's3://<SOME BUCKET>/asofdate=2021-03-03 00:00:00/';

ALTER TABLE spectrum.couponable_coupon
    SET TABLE PROPERTIES ('numRows'='<HELP HERE should be count(*) from my_external_table + count(*) from table_I_unloaded_to_s3 where asofdate='2021-03-03 00:00:00'>');
```